# IE10 inserting blank text DOM entries

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-10

I have a piece of Javascript code that locates the single table in the DOM then tries to manipulate its first child, the `thead` (actually, it iterates though the children of that child, the `tr` entries but that's not important to the question). The code to do this is:

```
var tableNode = document.getElementById("table").firstChild;
```

This works fine in Firefox ESR (10/17/24) and IE9 but fails in IE10, and the reason appears to be because IE10 is inserting weird DOM entries and it's one of those I'm picking up with `firstChild` instead of the desired `thead`. I base this on the DOM dump below along with the fact that `tableNode.data` is set to the string type.

The DOM in IE10 compatibility mode (where it also works) looks like this:

[image]

and you can see that the DOM indeed looks sensible. However, examining the DOM in normal IE10 mode shows this:

[image]

For what it's worth, Chrome gives me:

[image]

and FF17esr gives me:

[image]

neither of which seem to have the empty text elements.

Now, I can run the site in compatibility mode but that's an annoying thing to have to tell all our customers. I can also apparently add the hideous:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

to my output but I'm not entirely certain what other effects that may have.

I'd like to understand first *why* IE10 is adding these nodes whereas IE9/FF/IE10compat aren't. There are some discussions I've found stating that whitespace in the HTML may be causing it but it seems to me that this shouldn't result in random nodes being created and, in any case, I don't think I *have* any superfluous white space. Although I should mention that the *value* of `tableNode.data` mentioned above as type string is actually `\n`, meaning that the newline at the end of the line may be creating this DOM entry.

But, to be honest, that seems ludicrous. HTML is supposed to ignore whitespace outside of tags as far as I'm aware, or at least fold it into a single element. I find it hard to believe that something like:

```
<tag>line 1</tag>
<tag>line 2</tag>
```

would result in *three* DOM entries, `tag`, `empty node` and `tag` just because there's a newline between them.

Any ideas on how to best solve this? Am I going to have to modify my Javascript code to skip these DOM entries?

Comment: Ways to resolve this is described in my answer. Libraries like jQuery and YUI resolve it in similar ways. All browsers except IE9 and below do this. Don't look at the DOM inspector, test it with javascript code. See my answer for a test HTML file that you can run on various browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never know where a browser might insert text nodes so you have to make sure you're getting the first child "element"in case the browser put a text node there.

Here's a simple function that will do that:

```
getFirstChildElement(parent) {
    var node = parent.firstChild;
    // advance until we get to an element node (skipping text and comment nodes)
    while (node && node.nodeType !== 1) {
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
    return node;
}
```

Or, if you just want to get the `<thead>` element, you can simply use this:

```
table.getElementsByTagName("thead")[0]
```

Comment: What's the `1` in your `while` statement?

Comment: @paxdiablo - you can see the various nodeType values here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType.  `1` is an element node.

Answer (score 1):

Are you absolutely sure Firefox doesn't show those empty text nodes? I'm asking because it should, if it doesn't then it's a bug in Firefox.

Previously only IE behaved the way you expected. All other browsers including Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera followed W3C DOM standards which requires them to retain those whitespace. IE10 now join the ranks of other web browsers and behave in a standards compliant way.

You'd be right to complain that this doesn't make sense but it's what the standards require.

As such, the correct way to get the element is to check it's `tagName`:

```
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var child = table.firstChild;

while (child && child.tagName != 'thread') {
    child = child.nextSibling;
}

// remember to check child after this point because it may be undefined
```

---

### Additional explanation

Firebug and Chrome's DOM explorer hides those text elements as a matter of convenience, but it's still there. You can try this out:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="foo">
        <div id="bar">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var f = document.getElementById('foo');
        document.body.innerHTML += f.firstChild.id + <br>;
        document.body.innerHTML += f.firstChild.nextSibling.id + <br>;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In all browsers except older versions of IE the above page would output:

```
undefined
bar
```

That's because the `firstChild` is the empty text node. You can `console.log` it if you like to check out that `firstChild`.

Comment: Alternatively do what jfriend00 recommends and check that it's a tag rather than a text node or comment (yes, the DOM retains comments as well as required by the standards, and yes, previous versions of IE sometimes didn't do it)

Comment: I've added the DOM dump from Chrome and FF17esr. Neither of them appear to preserve the whitespace elements. Are you sure it's required by the standard?

Comment: Although in OP's case it's still weird, because there's just that many elements allowed inside `<table>`/`<tr>`/etc.. [Not allowed elements (including actual text) would generally rendered outside `<table>`](http://jsfiddle.net/Spcwn/). Comments may be special but generally you _know_ there's a comment, but line feeds and spaces are more or less tricking.

Comment: The DOM browser in FF and Chrome don't show the whitespace. But it's there in the DOM if you access it via javascript.

Comment: @Passerby: Ah, the table case may be unique then in that some browsers choose to render the whitespace outside the table. But the general case is still true: whitespace is preserved as text nodes.

Comment: @slebetman [Yes](http://jsfiddle.net/Spcwn/1/), that's why I said it's weird in OP's case. Whitespaces _IS_ generally preserved (especially between two inline elements), but in the case of `<table>`, preserving spaces seems weird and "not right". Actually, Chrome and Firefox recognize the first _allowed_ element as `firstChild` in my fiddle above.

Comment: slebetman, I'm not sure then how it works in those other browsers since I _am_ using JS to process the DOM. Unless firstChild and nextSibling skips empty text nodes, I should have the same problems in those browsers as I am in IE10 and that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: One thing I will mention is that the code doesn't currently push out a DOCTYPE in the HTML. I seem to recall that changes the idea of what whitespace is considered significant or not. I'll investigate that a little.

Comment: @paxdiablo: See my discussion with Passerby above. Tables may be unique in that generally text nodes are not allowed between tags and in this case the behavior may not be fully specified by the spec.